# Why the message is need in verify function

Tags: signature

here is the how bitcoin works under the hood article
http://www.imponderablethings.com/2013/07/how-bitcoin-works-under-hood.html
i did not got this why message is needed when using this verify function ?
1 =? v(message, public key, signature)

Answer (score 1):

Say you see a check for "$50,000 to Bob" that needs to be signed by Ed. What you want to know is whether the signature on the check came from Ed and signs the message "$50,000 to Bob". So the question a signature checker answers is, does the given signature attach the given credential to the given message. How would it check that without the message?

Checking a signature detached from a message would serve no purpose. Say you see that check for $50,000 to Bob. If Ed actually signed "$50 to Alice", the the signature check *must* fail -- since Ed didn't sign that message. So you *can't* check the signature without knowing the message.

Comment: Let me make an example about how is it works. Tugay sends 1 btc to David. Tugay signs it with his private key and broadcasts to the network. Miners verify the transaction like this: 1) solve digital signature with Tugay's public key, 2) compare the result with the hash of transaction 3) if its correct then verify the transaction and the output of this function: transaction = v(message, public key, signature) will be my address because transaction is made by me. Now do i got it right ?

Comment: @TugayÖztürk That's pretty close.